# Display next and previous page link only pages of a certain parent page

Tags: wordpress

Given the scenario

Parent Page

- sub page 1
- sub page 2
- sub page 3
- etc..

I want to display next/previous page link to Parent Page's subpages only
so on sub page 1 there will be a link pointing to sub page 2, and in sub page 2 another link pointing back to sub page 1 and sub page 3, so on..

basically I want to somewhat constraing next_post_link/previous_post_link to parent page's sub page only

Is this possible, how to acheive it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if a certain page is a sub page of another page. Then if true, use the nex_post_link() and previous_post_link to that page

code to check if a page is a sub page of another page

```
function is_child($page_id) { 
    global $post; 
    if( is_page() && ($post->post_parent == $page_id) ) {
       return true;
    } else { 
       return false; 
    }
}
```